# How to protect hidden field data from being change

Tags: php, html, security, paypal

I am using a plugin nice paypal lite button, where i am unsecure by the hidden fields which are carrying transaction money, merchant email id. By the firebug, I edited these field value and unfortunately my edited value successfully proceed to paypal.

I tried `readonly` and it is also not helpfull.
So what can I do for avoid this.....

```
$f .= '<input type="hidden"   name="business" value="'.$a['email'].'" readonly/>';
        $f .= '<input type="hidden" id="customer_name" name="cmd" value="'.$a['command'].'" readonly/>';
        $f .= '<input type="hidden"  name="item_name" value="'.$a['name'].'" readonly/>';
        $f .= '<input type="hidden" id="pay_amount" name="amount" value="'.$a['amount'].'" readonly/>';
```

any link, any idea, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to stop the changing of client-side HTML. You could try however storing the data in a PHP session?

Comment: keep those email and price in an encrypted format like base64_decode(<string>) and base64_encode(<string>) or by using salt()

Comment: so there is no way to make hidden field uneditable...

Comment: Everything is editable on client side. You have to verify server side if an operation can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you have to worry about*. Users are always going to be able to edit client side data.  So a person can change their data so they are sending payments elsewhere, this is the same as them logging into their account and sending payments anywhere they want.  What you have to worry about is people being able to change other users payment information.  I'm not a security expert but this is why you clean all dynamic data that is being displayed on your site (ie. Don't trust data in your database).  You can also serve the page via TLS to prevent the traffic from getting manipulated (by a compromised router for example).

Answer (score 1):

For the record

Step 1) generates a unique validation id.  So, if the information is altered, you could validate it again.

```
$key=md5($a['email'].$a['name']...$SOMESALT);
$f .= '<input type="hidden"   name="validation" value="'.$key.'" />';
```

Step 2) when you are validating the information, you could verify the integrity

```
$validation=@$_POST['validation'];
$key=md5(@$_POST['email'].@$_POST['name']...$SOMESALT); // again
if ($key!=$validation) {
    die('nope');
}
```

Optional: You could enforce the security by generating a random salt and storing in the session.

For this case, MD5 is pretty safe.